# What is a source reference note?

Tags: publications

In many manuscript preparation instructions there is this line in the instructions for notes:

"...A source reference note should be indicated by means of an asterisk after the title. This note should be placed at the bottom of the first page."

Anyone knows what a "source reference note" is and maybe have an example?

Comment: Perhaps they mean *funding source*? Putting a note saying something like "This work was partially supported by (Funding Agency) under grant no. (no)" is quite common on the title page. This paper has one: https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.13344 - also with an asterisk after the title.

Comment: Without a context this is difficult to answer. Do you have a link to the manuscript guidelines? In general, it may be best to ask the editorial team for clarification.

Comment: Here's a link (see the notes section): https://www.springer.com/journal/10670/submission-guidelines#Instructions%20for%20Authors_Manuscript%20Presentation

Comment: https://www.cerl.org/resources/cerl_thesaurus/editing/format/321